# Not able to push XMLSlurper result into a Set

Tags: groovy, set

I am starting to work with Groovy (2.4.12) the engine will have the same version and Java 1.8.0_271
I am trying to find unique values from the result of XMLSlurper so trying to push to a Set.
But I get the complete list instead of the unique values.

This is the snippet code:

```
        import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message
        import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
        import java.time.LocalDate
        import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
        import java.text.DecimalFormat
        import java.util.HashSet
        
def Message processData(Message message) {
        Reader reader = message.getBody(Reader)
        def DELVRY07 = new XmlSlurper().parse(reader)
            
        
            Set mySet = DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDL24.VGBEL.toSet();
                    //println mySet.size()
                    mySet.each { order ->
                        println order
                    }
        return message;
    }
```

Input XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<DELVRY07>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
         <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                <VGBEL>0010001035</VGBEL>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                <VGBEL>0010001036</VGBEL>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                <POSNR>900001</POSNR>
                <VGBEL>0010001035</VGBEL>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                <POSNR>900002</POSNR>
                <VGBEL>0010001035</VGBEL>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                <POSNR>900003</POSNR>
                <VGBEL>0010001036</VGBEL>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                <POSNR>900004</POSNR>
                <VGBEL>0010001036</VGBEL>
            </E1EDL24>
            <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                <POSNR>900005</POSNR>               
                <VGBEL>0010001036</VGBEL>
            </E1EDL24>
        </E1EDL20>
      </IDOC>
</DELVRY07>
```

Output

```
0010001035
0010001036
0010001036
0010001036
0010001035
0010001035
0010001036
```

There are only two unique values, so the expected result is only 0010001035 and 0010001036.

I would really appreciate any comment or advice.
Thank you,

Ric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_groovy/tree/master/stack_overflow_65404412).

Consider the following code (modified somewhat re: `Message`):

```
def Message processData(Message message) {
    def reader = message.getBody()
    def DELVRY07 = new XmlSlurper().parse(reader)

    // crucial code:
    def mySet = DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDL24.VGBEL.inject(new HashSet(),{
        acc, node -> acc << node.text()
    })
    
    mySet.each { order ->
        println order
    }

    return message;
}
```

The problem with the original code is that the GPath expression returns `NodeChildren` which will print to the console as though it were a String value, but it is its own object, so using `text()` is important.

Comment: This is working nice, I tried toString().toSet() any hint on why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working - xmlslurper accessors returning gpathresult object that is not comparable

Use toString transformation before toSet.

Like this

```
...VGBEL*.toString().toSet()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried `Set mySet = DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDL24.VGBEL.toString().toSet() `  but I get 0, 1, 3, 5, 6 as a result.

Comment: `.*toString()` asterisk is important

Comment: I have tried the same solution but following sintax `Set mySet = DELVRY07.IDOC.E1EDL20.E1EDL24.VGBEL*.toString().toSet()` and is working thank you